# How to fix it? By pressing "Print Summary", there are extra 2 blank pages printed

Tags: drupal, search, debugging

By pressing "Print Summary", there are extra 2 blank pages printed. One of them is before the content and the other is after. How can I make them disappear? I'm using CiviCRM version 5.10.4.
Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Josh89 - good on you for adding those images etc, but those 'Answers' will likely get down voted as they are not answers. any reason you were not able to Edit your question and add the extra info there which is the expected approach

Comment: This doesn't happen to me on my test site.  Is this problem still present?  If so, can you replicate it on a demo server at https://demo.civicrm.org?  If not, it's probably a Drupal theme or module that's adding additional spacing, and you can experiment by disabling modules to see if you can isolate the one causing you grief.

Answer (score 0):

I have added some pictures to show the problem.
[image]